# Longest MySQL queries for worst case testing

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a big mysql Database (planned is about one million entries) and I want to test its performance by creating a worst query (longest calculation time) i am able to.

For now it is a database with two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user  (ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    createdAt DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                    lastAction DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                    ip TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                    browser TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY (ID))

CREATE TABLE evt  (ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                   UID BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                   timeStamp DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                   name TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
                   FOREIGN KEY (UID)
                   REFERENCES user(ID))
```

It's populated and is running locally so no connection is required.
Are there any rules of Thumb on how to create horrible queries?

My worst query for now was:

```
SELECT user.browser, evt.name, count(*) as AmountOfActions
    FROM evt
    JOIN user ON evt.UID = user.ID
    GROUP BY user.browser, evt.name
    ORDER BY AmountOfActions DESC
```

Comment: "Worst query" is a bit ephemeral and not something you can really do much with. I mean, you could just join a table to itself a dozen times on a hard to evaluate condition that almost always ends up true; so you end up with an exponentially huge cross product that took a long time to compute.

Comment: What you are proposing is a unique approach to performance tuning I have never encountered before. The usual method is to run explain plans on your queries, tune your database, and address bottlenecks as they occur. The best looking sql could turn out to be the worst performing query based on indexes and database settings. You may want to reconsider your approach.

Comment: @Uueerdo okay, means i want to make the database work on the most entries. You are right, the question is horribly built, but your answer told me something.
I was expecting an answer like "use GROUP BY alot" or "use custom functions (like count() or date()) alot"

Comment: @SamM i am pretty new to performance testing on SQL and i have never thought of a way to calculate the performance yet. Though worst case is pretty logical since it's used to test the performance of almost everything.
I will read somewhat about what you have said and test it that way instead if it's what i am looking for.

Comment: @Shuumi the biggest issue with this approach is there is little benefit to performance testing against queries that will never actually be executed; and no matter what "worst query" you come up with, there can always be a worse one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number one cost in a query is disk hits.  So, make a table big enough so that it cannot be cached in RAM.  And/or do a cross-join (etc) such that an intermediate table is too big to be cached in RAM.

A common problem on this forum is lots of joins followed by a group by.  Or lots of joins, plus an order by on the big intermediate result.

Here's a double-whammy -- join two tables (each too big to be cached) on a UUID.

Comment: Yeah. after @Uueerdo's comment i tried those tricks. I increased the Memory  to 1 GB and still had to decrease the maximum rows to somewhere about 4 Millions. Joining evt with user took about 8 seconds to save the results on a ResultSet with JDBC. Thank you very much for your answer!